# Is a symmetric real matrix similar to a diagonal matrix through an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices, similar-matrices

> **Definition**
>
> Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said similar if there exist an inverible matrix $P$ such that
> $$
> B=PAP^{-1}
> $$
>
> **Definition**
>
> A square matrix $A$ is said orthogonal if it is invertible and its inverse $A^{-1}$ is equals to its transpose $A^{tr}$ , that is
> $$
> AA^{tr}=I
> $$
>
> **Theorem**
>
> Any real symmetric (square) matrix is diagonalizzable and in particular its eingevectors form an orthonormal base.

So by the last theorem we know that any real symmetric matrix is ​​similar to a diagonal matrix and in particular the base of the latter is orthonormal but unfortunately I do not able to argue if the matrix $P$ above defined is in this case orthogonal. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a real symmetric matrix, then by the first part of the theorem, it is diagonalizable, that is

$$M = P D P^{-1}$$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries equal to the eigenvalues of $M$, and where the columns in $P$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. What we need to show is that the matrix $P$ can in fact be chosen to be orthogonal. To see this, we need the other part of the theorem, namely that $M$ has an *orthonormal* basis of eigenvectors. By choosing an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, the corresponding $P$ becomes orthogonal.

Comment: Okay I knew this: could you explain why the column of $P$ are the correponding eigenvectors? Indeed I know that the column of $P$ are the coordinate of the base of $M$ calculate with respect the base of $D$ that is orthormal. Excuse me my confusion.

Comment: In general, writing $A = S T S^{-1}$ for some invertible $S$ means $T$ is the matrix representation of the corresponding linear transformation with respect to the basis consisting of the columns of $S$ (since $S$ is the coordinate transformation matrix from the basis consisting of its columns to the standard basis, and $S^{-1}$ is the coordinate transformation matrix in the opposite direction). If $T$ is diagonal, that means $A$ acts on the columns of $S$ by simply multiplying with the scalar entries on the diagonal, i.e. the columns of $S$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I belive to do not know this: could you explain, please? Indeed I know that if $A$ is the matrix of a linear application $f$ with respect the bases $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$ then the matrix $B$ of $f$ with respect the bases $\mathcal V'$ and $\mathcal W'$ is given by the formula $$B=QAP^{-1}$$ where the column of $Q$ are the coordinate of $\mathcal W$ with respect $\mathcal W'$ and the column of $P^{-1}$ are the coordinate of $\mathcal V'$ with respect of $\mathcal V$, that's right? So could you give some clarification? Sorry, forgive a lot my confusion.

Comment: In the notation of your comment, $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ would be identical, in particular they would be an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $B$. $\mathcal{V}'$ and $\mathcal{W}$' would also be identical, they would both be the standard basis. $A$ would then be diagonal, as it is the representation of a linear transformation wrt. an eigenbasis ($\mathcal{V}$), and we would have $Q=P$ with columns equal to the $\mathcal{V}$-basis vectors, since those are the coordinates of the $\mathcal{V}$-basis vectors wrt. the standard basis. That is, it is exactly the form you need.

Comment: Sorry, why $\mathcal V'$ and $\mathcal W'$ would be the standard basis? Indeed a matrix of a linear transformation could be calculate using many different bases!!! Anyway is the standard basis the basis $$(1,0,....,0),\,\,\,(0,1,....,0,1)\,\,\,...\,\,\,(0,0,....,0,1)$$ right?

Comment: Because the linear transformation $\mathbf{v} \mapsto B \mathbf{v}$ is represented by $B$ in the standard basis. And yes, the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $(\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \dots, \mathbf{e}_n)$, where $\mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a one in the $i$'th coordinate and zeroes everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the problem is, if $\lbrace e_1, ..., e_n \rbrace$ forms an orthonormal basis, then $P := (e_1~ ...~ e_n)$ is an orthogonal matrix. We just go by the matrix multiplication formula. Let $B := A^{tr}A$. Then for $i, j \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace$ we have:
$$
(B)_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (A^{tr})_{ik}(A)_{kj} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (A)_{ki}A_{kj} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (e_i)_k (e_j)_k = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle
$$
$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Because of the orthonormal base property, we have $(B)_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $(B)_{ij} = 0$ if $i \neq j$.m So $B = I$. Therefore:
$$
(AA^{tr}) = B^{tr} = I^{tr} = I 
$$